# The website it opens using the automated software closes soon after it gets executed

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

Error could possibly be in line 7,
it should open the browser search for the specific word then should the window should stay until closed

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/daniy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts/chromedriver.exe")

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        driver.implicitly_wait(6000)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        driver.implicitly_wait(5000)
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        driver.implicitly_wait(6000)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        driver.implicitly_wait(6000)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
        driver.implicitly_wait(9000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(5000) why you using so many implicit wait

Answer (score 0):

You should use the right version of ChromeDrive as per your browser

refer to this link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Try the below code it should work

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/daniy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts/chromedriver.exe")


    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.implicitly_wait(6000)
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        time.sleep(6000)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(6000)            
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Same issue.....the test window closes soon after the execution

Answer (score 0):

Try this out it works for me.

```
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
elem=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
self.assertNotIn("No results found.", driver.page_source)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```